# how to count or extract Cases out of list of association that matches pattern

Tags: filtering, associations

I have list of associations

```
lr1 = {<|a -> {0,0}, b -> "TRUE"|>, <|b -> "FALSE", a -> {0,1}|>, <|a -> {1,0}, b -> "FALSE"|>, <|b -> "TRUE", a -> {1,1}|>}
```

and I would like to count number of associations in a list `lr1` that matches pattern that key `b` is associated with value `"TRUE"`.

Similarly, to extract new list of associations, with only those that matches the sam pattern as in case of counting.

Keys `a` and `b` does not necessary have unique positions through associations.

I need to solve this with Mathematica functions `Count` and `Cases`.

Comment: "I need to solve this with Mathematica functions `Count` and `Cases`." - why the restriction, if other approaches can be more compact or efficient?

Comment: @J.M. - the list of associations is few x `10^6`, so primary function is to count acceptable assoc. Next step is extraction. I would avoid making any operations before counting. So, this is reason for counting first.
But if this is possible, without generating new datalist please post it.

Comment: So, would `Length @* Select[MatchQ["TRUE"] @* Lookup[b]] @ lr1` fit the bill?

Comment: @J.M. it works. Please could you explain and/or reference to meaning of `@*` .

Comment: That's the infix form of `Composition[]`.

Comment: `Count[Lookup[lr1, b], "TRUE"]` or `Count[lr1, "TRUE", {0, ∞}]`

Answer (score 4):

This is a good use case for [`KeyValuePattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValuePattern.html):

```
Count[KeyValuePattern[b -> "TRUE"]] @ lr1
```

> 2